# What is the NACA Series of the Rockwell B-1b's wing design?

Tags: wing, rockwell-b-1-lancer

I can't find any information about the airfoil of the Rockwell B-1b. It's listed as a NACA 69-190-2, which doesn't follow the conventional format of the 6-Series airfoils. I'm assuming its a design unique to Rockwell but I thought it would still be listed in the [airfoiltools](http://airfoiltools.com) database. I cannot find any information about it. Jane's has a write up in the 86-87 edition but only mentions the leading edge dimensions.

From Jane's:

> Wings:
> Cantilever low-wing fail-safe blended wing body structure, with variable geometry on outer panels. ...
>
> Each of the outer wing panels, which have 15" of leading-edge sweep when fully forward and 67" 30' when fully swept, is a conventional two-spar aluminium alloy torsion box structure, with machined spars, ribs, and one-piece integrally stiffened top and bottom skin panels.
>
> Full span seven-segment leading-edge slats on each outer panel can be drooped 20" for take-off and landing.
>
> Six-segment single-slotted trailing-edge flaps on
> each outer panel, with maximum downward deflection of 40°.

Comment: I've retracted my vote to close, since the "why spoilers & not ailerons for roll control" question was separated out. This question is now appropriately focused, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not listed as NACA ..., it is listed as NA 69-190-2. When the development contract for the B1 was [awarded in 1970](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockwell_B-1_Lancer#B-1A_program), North American and Rockwell [had already merged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockwell_International#Rockwell_Manufacturing_Company). Hence, I am assuming that NA stands for North American and that it is a proprietary airfoil. Since the B1 flies at high subsonic speeds when the wings are extended, I would assume that the airfoil is a supercritical one, which also rules out a NACA 6-series airfoil.